# css/html Table border

Tags: html, css

I would like to options for making tables in my css. One with a border of 5px solid black and one with 0px.  Currently in CSS i have

```
#contentcolumn table {
border: 5px solid black;
width: 100%;/*around 700 max for images*/
border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

That gives me the black 5px border, but now i need to also have one that does 0px border. 
I have tried setting the 0px table in html but the css seems to over ride it.  here is the html for the two tables.

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td align="center"><IMG SRC="images/newsimage/minecraft1.jpg" ALT="mindcraft">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Is minecraft still considered an indie game? blah blah blha lbhalbhal
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>


        <!-- Reviews start -->
        <!-- Review #1 -->
        <table Border='0'>
        <tr>
          <th rowspan="4" width="30%">Some Image</th>
          <td>Link</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>By who</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Some info</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>comments</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
```

both tables are inside div tags `<div id="contentcolumn">` if that matters?

Comment: i cant understand well did you need both of the tables need no-border?or one need border and other don't?

Comment: Put individual id or class all table and then set `border`

Comment: one needed border and one not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to give `border:none` into style attribute. It will overwrite your css properties in css file. `<table style="border:none;">`

Comment: Although this really should be using a selector in the style sheet, not inline.

Comment: It did work, would like to see this done in css. If i dont get another answer on how to do it in css ill approve it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

CSS:

```
.no-border {
   border:none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<table class="no-border"></table>
```

Comment: this did not work , still showed border.  I went with first way with html

Answer (score 0):

You can done this using css itself. By using below css style

```
#contentcolumn #review_table{border:0px}
```

and add a id in your table like below

```
<div id="contentcolumn">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td align="center"><IMG SRC="images/newsimage/minecraft1.jpg" ALT="mindcraft">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Is minecraft still considered an indie game? blah blah blha lbhalbhal
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>


    <!-- Reviews start -->
    <!-- Review #1 -->
    <table Border='0' id="review_table"> //CHANGE: ADD THE ID TO THIS TABLE
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="4" width="30%">Some Image</th>
      <td>Link</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>By who</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some info</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>comments</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

​

JSFILLDE:

http://jsfiddle.net/54EyB/